# Is it possible to collect signal strength coming from nearby Wi-Fi devices, modems etc.?

Tags: android, flutter, wifi, android-wifi, rssi

I have a Flutter app that I collect datas of nearby beacons like mac address, rssi, distance etc. I want to do the same thing for wi-fi devices like modems etc.

Googled it but couldn't find something clear. Is it possible? Btw it is OK. if it's working for android but not ios.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_hunter Check this package